# Templated function not found when used inside a class

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to use templates and I have a compilation error that I don't understand.

The code:

```
#include <QList>

template <typename T>
bool getBytesFromFrame(
        QList<unsigned char>::ConstIterator *iterator,
        T &val, const int numBytes,
        QList<unsigned char>::ConstIterator &listEnd) // ERROR HERE
{
    return true;
}


class Parser
{
public:
    Parser(const unsigned char buffer[], const int numBytes){
    }
    ~Parser(){}

    template <class T>
    bool next(T &data, const int numBytes)
    {
        return getBytesFromFrame(&it, data, numBytes, frame.constEnd());
    }

    QList<unsigned char> frame;

private:
    QList<unsigned char>::ConstIterator it;
};
```

The compiler complains about:

> ..\SandBox/test.h: In member function 'bool Parser::next(T&, int)
>   [with T = int]': ..\SandBox\main.cpp:58: instantiated from here
>
> ..\SandBox/test.h:27: error: no matching function for call to
>   'getBytesFromFrame(QList::const_iterator*, int&, const
>   int&, QList::const_iterator)'

I don't understand why the parameter #3 becomes a `const int&` during the call to `getBytesFromFrame`.
This is `numBytes` that is a `const int` parameter of function `next` and that is transmitted as a reference `const int&`.

Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: The last parameter of `getBytesFromFrame` is a non-const reference (a reference to a type not marked as `const`). You cannot bind temporaries to such parameters. `frame.constEnd()` returns a prvalue (temporary).

Comment: *"I don't understand why the parameter #3 becomes a `const int&` during the call"* You compiler seems to show you the argument list (not the function parameters), where the reference-qualification indicates the value category of the argument expressions. `numBytes` is an lvalue, hence it appends a `&`.

Comment: Ok! So I need to learn about prvalues and lvalues to understand what you say. Thanks!

Comment: Could you tell me how to solve this please? Thanks!

Comment: Iterators are generally designed to be passed by value, so if you don't need to modify the iterator, just remove the reference.

Comment: Change `QList<unsigned char>::ConstIterator &listEnd` to `QList<unsigned char>::ConstIterator listEnd` and call me in the morning.  Only take things by reference if you intend for modifications within the function to propagate out.  If you do intend that, then don't pass temporaries in to arguments you want to propagate values out, because that makes no sense.

Comment: Many thanks to all of you: it works now :)!!!